# How to prove a statement with multiple conditionals

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Suppose I have a claim to prove:

If x and y are distinct real numbers, then $$(x+1)^2=(y+1)^2$$ iff
$$ x+y = -2$$

$$\n$$
In order to solve this do I tackle the if and only if part first?

i.e.

Prove $$(x+1)^2 = (y+1)^2 => x+y = -2 $$ and

$$x+y = -2 => (x+1)^2 = (y+1)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to break it up in that manner. If you start factoring, you get
$$(x+1)^2=(y+1)^2$$
$$\iff (x+1 +y+1)(x+1-y-1)=0$$
$$\iff x+y=-2 \textrm{ or } x=y$$

Now since you are given that $x$ and $y$ are distinct, the second equation is always false, so this is equivalent to

$$x +y=-2$$
as required.